# How to canced onbeforeupload confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, warnings, onbeforeunload

Is there a way to hide the confirm dialog when onbeforeunload is called ?

I tried with :

return null 
return 0
return an empty var (undefined)
return false
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.stopPropagation();

But nothing work. I use firefox and chrome.

My code

```
window.onbeforeunload = test;
function test(){
    // some code
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: withouth result the code is not run.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't return anything and the function will just execute your `//some code` if it has the time :p No setTimeout, no sleep are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!  You right!  The problem come from the fact of my command isn't fully executed. I would like to send a message through a websocket connection. With no result, the server doesn't receive anything but the same code work with a returned value (and a confirm message box). Someone know how to force run my command completely? I don't need any server response, I just want to send data to my server.

The code I would like to run is

```
websocket.send(data);
```

Where websocket is an opened connection to my server.

But like healkiss said, the function finish before my command have sent data. I don't understand why the function continue and end before data are sent.